# Как отсортировать список Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я только начинаю свой путь в Python. Простите за корявость, если что.

Имею такую задачу. Вернуть список, который содержит те же элементы, что и  элементы аргумента, но с обратным порядком элементов внутри каждого максимального строго возрастающего подсписка.

Пример:

`[5, 7, 10, 4, 2, 7, 8, 1, 3]` - аргумент функции.
`[10, 7, 5, 4, 8, 7, 2, 3, 1]` - то, что должна функция вернуть.

Мой код:

```
def reverse_ascending(items):
     sort_items=sorted(items,reverse=True)  #обратно-отсортированный список
     list_sort_1=sort_items[::2]            #получаю  список с первым макс.значением
     list_sort_2=sort_items[1::2]           #получаю список со вторым макс.значением
     print(list_sort_1+list_sort_2)
```

Comment: Вы в первой же строчке теряете информацию о подсписках. А вам нужно а) их найти, и б) уже потом с ними работать. Ну или не потом, а сразу во время поиска.

Comment: И заголовок ваш совсем не о том. Задача совсем не о сортировке списка (это как раз легко), более того, сортировать в этой задаче вообще не требуется.

Comment: Благодарю за коментарий! Мышление заострилось на сортировке-не видел задачу с другого угла.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [5, 7, 10, 4, 2, 7, 8, 1, 3]

res = []

pos_s = 0
pos_f = 1

while pos_s < len(data):
    # найти границы возрастающей последовательности    
    while pos_f < len(data) and data[pos_f] > data[pos_f - 1]:
        pos_f += 1

    # добавить к результату найденную последовательность в обратном порядке
    part = data[pos_s:pos_f]
    res += part[::-1]

    pos_s, pos_f = pos_f, pos_f + 1

print(res)
```

Comment: Сортировать же нет необходимости. Достаточно же [::-1]  или даже reverse()

Comment: да, просто что-то я мудрил со срезами и в итоге просто воткнул сортировку, сейчас заменю, просто хотелось сразу из `data` вырезать и что-то не получалось :)